# When does a service instance get disposed of in WCF

Tags: wcf

So there are 3 options when it comes to creating a service instance in WCF:

1. Per Call
2. Per Session
3. Singleton

I know that in the case of option 1 the instance will be disposed of as soon as the service completes the call.

My question is what about the other 2 options? When and how are service instances that were created per session or as singleton disposed?

Comment: Easy - Whenever the GC decides to.

Comment: So when the client calls the close() method in the proxy the client-server connection is closed but the service instance stays alive?

Comment: The object will be garbage collected by the runtime. This is not something you have to concern yourself with in a managed language.